The attachment in my automated flow is corrupted
I have the following flow setup.
Manually trigger a flow --> Get file content --> Send an email
The attachment part of "Send an email" looks as below.

The issue when running the flow is shown below. I get the error that the file is corrupted.


Can you give us the expression for the file content you’ve shown in the second screenshot?

You can use this expression instead of using Dynamic content:
like triggerOutputs()?['body']['file']['contentBytes']

This will give you the content of the file.

I recommend against saying thanks for the privilege of providing answer. ;-) It risks being misread as the whole post only being "Thanks", i.e. not an aswer according to [answer]. At least by the more doggedly minded entities. Also you might enjoy this info for making your post look better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

I tried to help you with formatting, but I suspect I did not get the syntax entirely right (it is why code-formatting is so useful in an answer...). Please [edit] and fix what I probably broke.

I'm having this issue when a PDF, Word, or Excel file is submitted via "Manually Trigger a Flow" then attached to "Start and Wait for Approval"
